# How to access update the next context a user should go to [DialogFlow Fulfillment]

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using contexts within Dialogflow to call the next intent for the user. What I would like to do is have the ability for someone to change their mind on an answer they just entered. For example, as seen in the image below, if I enter a name then it would ask for an email. However, the user should be able to say "can I change my name" and go back to the context where Dialogflow is asking for a name.

I already have that intent implemented but I am trying to figure out how to go back to the question they were going to answer before deciding to change their name. I can use fulfillment to capture the raw API response and possibly get the last context however how can I force the user after changing their name to go back their previous context/intent?   [image: example of how I am using context to call the next intent]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using the fulfillment. You have to save the previous intent contexts and prompt as well as the next intent contexts and prompt in the parameters of the intent.

Comment: Ok yeah I understand I need to save the intent and or add parameters which Incan get in the raw api response. However I am not sure how to write the json to send a response back to the user using json with an output context from my webhook.